# Use WinFormElementHost in Popup

Tags: c#, wpf

First, I apologize for my weak foundation in English
I want to show my win form user control in a popup but this not displayed WinFormElementHost! 
what can I do for this ?

Edit:

this are my code, xaml codes for define popup and my user control class

```
        <Popup Name="popupDate" PopupAnimation="Scroll" Width="310" Height="310" 
           PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=buttonDate}" 
           AllowsTransparency="True" Margin="8,-36,-29,-13">
        <Canvas Background="Transparent">
            <Canvas Background="LightBlue" Width="300" Height="300">
                <Canvas.BitmapEffect>
                    <DropShadowBitmapEffect Softness=".3" 
                                            ShadowDepth=".5" 
                                            Color="Black"/>
                </Canvas.BitmapEffect>
                <WindowsFormsHost Height="200" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0"   Name="windowsFormsHost1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200"/>
            </Canvas>
        </Canvas>
    </Popup>



public partial class SearchBaseDateAndDuration : UserControl
{
    Persian_Calender.Persian_Calender pc;
    public SearchBaseDateAndDuration()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pc = new Persian_Calender.Persian_Calender();

        windowsFormsHost1.Child = pc;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your attention

Good Luck

Comment: any code you can share of failed attempts

Comment: this code no have any error , but don't show my user control and i use popup easily

Comment: I don't understand how that supposed to work what you do. There has to be some kind of WinForms control _inside_ the `WindowsFormsHost` XAML tag. See here a `DataGridView` http://mindstick.com/Articles/e87470a2-1aac-4d2a-a645-f3d9e90ba555/?WindowsFormsHost%20control%20in%20WPF or here a `MaskedTextBox` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.windowsformshost.aspx. In your case it would be a special calendar control? Or a full dialog in a UserControl? The `WindowsFormsHost` is empty.

Comment: tank for your help, i test my user control in popup but without canvas tag and no have problem , now how can i show my control in popup and canvas tag ?   i need canvas for drop shadow effect on popup

Comment: may you please answer me

Comment: i have problem with show winForms control in canvas tag in popup - without canvas or other panels can put just one control in popup

Answer (score 0):

Can you use a grid, and then put both the WindowsFormsHost and the Canvas in the grid (with the WindowsFormHost on top)?